# How to understand the unix time format?

Tags: date, timestamps

How does the Unix time format work? For example, the Unix time for 3:00 PM is:

```
Normal time format <----3:00PM = 1402565420----> Unix Time
```

How can I make it understand the time as **3:00 PM** ?

Comment: 1402565420 may be 3pm on a specific date in your specific timezone. Tomorrow 3pm in your timezone will be 1402651820. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time for details: "Unix time (aka POSIX time or Epoch time), is a system for describing instants in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970."

Comment: To convert these tomestamps, try `date -d @1402565420` or `TZ=your-timezone-abbreviation date -d @1402565420`.

Comment: Wow Cool the command Works Perfect

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Unix time is given as [seconds since the epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time): the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) that have passed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), or Thursday, January 1st, 1970,

The GNU `date` command has some very nice features that allow you to translate between different time formats. These are explained very nicely in `man date` so I will only give you some examples here:

```
### "Normal" format
$ date
Thu Jun 12 11:44:23 CEST 2014
### Unix time
$ date +%s
1402566271
```

To convert, you can give `date` a specific date using the `-d` flag. However, to get a Unix date, this needs to be a full date. You can't convert 3:00PM to Unix time since Unix time refers to an entire date (year,month,day,time). So, for example, to get the Unix date for the 12th of September 1987, you would do:

```
$ date -d "3 PM 12 September 1987" +%s
558450000
```

And to convert that back to a "normal" date:

```
$ date -d "@558450000" 
Sat Sep 12 15:00:00 CEST 1987
```

Comment: `date -d 3pm` will still work and is the same as `date -d "3pm today"`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas yes, but as you said, it will give _today_'s time. The point I was making to the OP is that `3:00PM` is meaningless in terms of Unix time and only `3:00 PM today` makes sense.

Comment: I suggest that it should be noticed that Unix time is absolute, while my "3pm today" can be very different from your "3pm today"... depending on `$TZ`.

Comment: @Rmano, yes, and also note that things like `1am` can be ambiguous as in most countries (the ones implementing DST)  there is one day of the year where  that time occurs twice.